# Laravel: Get a list of items and SUM

Tags: laravel, sum, strpos

It is hard to make a question!
Well, I have this object from $request:

```
{
"_method": "POST",
"_token": null,
"cliente": "1",
"cota": "853",
"grupo": "07384",
"idERP": "1",
"novoSegmento": "3",
"nrocpfCnpj": "00635344000177",
"natureza_juridica": "206-2 - Sociedade Empresária Limitada",
"porte": "MICRO EMPRESA",
"originalSegmento": "7",
"example_length": "10",
"cota853": "12975",
"cota209": "12110"
}
```

I must sum the values from the cota*** and it is quite tricky to do.
First I´ve searched for the word 'cota' within this $result using:

```
if (strpos($request, 'cota') !== false) {
            return 'true';
        }
```

From now on, I can´t figure out how to continue:
1-) Get how many 'cota'?
2-) How to get each value to make the sum?

Any ideas? Is this the best way?
I hope I made myself clear.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are passing this using a form, you can better make an array of `cotas` and then sum them using the powerful collection in laravel, like this:

```
// in your blade

<input name="cota[]" value="100" />
<input name="cota[]" value="200" />

// in the controller

$total = collect($request->get('cota'))->sum();
```

or iterate over the request values and sum the cota:

```
$total = 0;
foreach ( $request->all() as $key => $value )
{
    if (strpos($key, 'cota') !== false) {
        $total += $value;
    }

    // or regex version to exclude the cota
    if ( preg_match('/cota[0-9]+/', $key) )
    {
        $total += $value;
    }

}

// here you will have the total sum
```

Comment: Thanks man! But the result of the sum is different, like:
I´ve selected two 'cotas':
cota853 = 12975
cota 835 = 11945

The result should be 24920, but it shows: 25773

You may know why?

Comment: Try debugging it, inside the `if` condition add this: `dump($key, $value);` this will print out each time the condition is met, and you will see why

Comment: That´s the result of the dump, Check this out:
**"cota"
"853"
"cota853"
"12975"
"cota835"
"11945"
25773
**

Comment: It does the sum with the first 853 that appears, and it should not!

Comment: Check my edit, use the regex version. You never mentioned that you want to exclude the `cota` without any number from the sum.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert the request into a collection and do a sum with a callback like below:

```php
$sum = collect($request->all())->filter(function ($value, $key) {
    return Str::startsWith($key, 'cota');
})->sum();
```

---

Comment: This return an error:
**Too few arguments to function App\Http\Controllers\DocumentoController::App\Http\Controllers\{closure}(), 1 passed in /Users/marcellopato/Sites/primorossi/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Support/Collection.php on line 1766 and exactly 2 expected**

Comment: @MarcelloPatto check the update. Changed to filter/sum instead of just sum because it appears that the sum callback does not accept the key